# enumerable group field using Linq?

Tags: linq

I've written a Linq sentence like this:

```
var fs = list
    .GroupBy(i =>
        new { 
            X = i.X,
            Ps = i.Properties.Where(p => p.Key.Equals("m"))  <<<<<<<<<<<
        }
    )
    .Select(g => g.Key });
```

Am I able to group by `IEnumerable.Where(...)` fields?

Comment: which data structures do you use? what is `list`, `i`, `X`, `Properties`?

Answer (score 0):

The grouping won't work here.

When grouping, the runtime will try to compare group keys in order to produce proper groups. However, since in the group key you use a property (`Ps`) which is a distinct `IEnumerable<T>` for each item in `list` (the comparison is made on reference equality not on sequence equality) this will result in a different collection for each element; in other words if you'll have two items:

```
var a = new { X = 1, Properties = new[] { "m" } };
var b = new { X = 1, Properties = new[] { "m" } };
```

The `GroupBy` clause will give you two distinct keys as you can see from the image below.

[image: Grouping result]

If your intent is to just project the items into the structure of the `GroupBy` key then you don't need the grouping; the query below should give the same result:

```
var fs = list.Select(item => new
{
    item.X,
    Ps = item.Properties.Where(p => p.Key == "m")
});
```

However, if you do require the results to be distinct, you'll need to create a separate class for your result and implement a separate [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) to be used with [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) clause:

```
public class Result
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Ps { get; set; }
}

public class ResultComparer : IEqualityComparer<Result>
{
    public bool Equals(Result a, Result b)
    {
        return a.X == b.X && a.Ps.SequenceEqual(b.Ps);
    }

    // Implement GetHashCode
}
```

Having the above you can use `Distinct` on the first query to get distinct results:

```
var fs = list.Select(item => new Result
{
    X = item.X,
    Ps = item.Properties.Where( p => p.Key == "m")
}).Distinct(new ResultComparer());
```